# r filter by group multiple critera

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a dataset with student scores. There are a lot of repeat rows per student ID like this below.

```
       ID    Date       Score    Source
       1     2016-02-24 19.2     A
       2     2020-01-08 16.6     B
       3     2021-01-25 18.1     A
       3     2021-01-25 16.2     C
       4     2011-02-28 13.2     A
       4     2011-02-28 17.4     A
       5     2011-02-28 19.2     A
       5     2011-02-28 14.6     C
       6     2016-04-16 11.2     C
       6     2016-04-16 12.4     C
```

My goal is to exclude some repeat observations and retain only observations based on this criteria.

Rule 1 : Same ID, Same date, different source. Retain only rows where Source = A
Example ID 3, 5 , retain row

```
      3     2021-01-25 18.1     A
      5     2011-02-28 19.2     A
```

Rule 2 : Same ID, Same date, same source. Retain rows with max of score.

```
     4     2011-02-28 17.4     A
     6     2016-04-16 12.4     C
```

The final expected dataset

```
      ID    Date       Score    Source
       1     2016-02-24 19.2     A
       2     2020-01-08 16.6     B
  
       3     2021-01-25 18.1     A
      
       4     2011-02-28 17.4     A
  
       5     2011-02-28 19.2     A
        
       6     2016-04-16 12.4     C
```

I am aware of groupby and filter but I am not sure how to apply those functions in this situation. Any suggestion is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Is the end of “rule 1” cut off?

Comment: @zephryl, not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was just misreading and confused. Disregard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(ID, Date) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Source) == 1L | Source == "A") %>%
  group_by(ID, Date, Source) %>%
  summarize(Score = max(Score), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#      ID Date       Source Score
#   <int> <chr>      <chr>  <dbl>
# 1     1 2016-02-24 A       19.2
# 2     2 2020-01-08 B       16.6
# 3     3 2021-01-25 A       18.1
# 4     4 2011-02-28 A       17.4
# 5     5 2011-02-28 A       19.2
# 6     6 2016-04-16 C       12.4
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), Date = c("2016-02-24", "2020-01-08", "2021-01-25", "2021-01-25", "2011-02-28", "2011-02-28", "2011-02-28", "2011-02-28", "2016-04-16", "2016-04-16"), Score = c(19.2, 16.6, 18.1, 16.2, 13.2, 17.4, 19.2, 14.6, 11.2, 12.4), Source = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: not sure why it says `Error in summarize(., Score = max(Score))) : argument "by" is missing, with default`

Comment: i changed `summarize ` to `summarise` and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: not sure why after these steps all my other columns are dropped. I only have 4 columns .

Comment: (1) your `by` problem is probably because you also have the `plyr`package loaded. Type just `summarize` on the console, and after the source code it will say the package/environment. (2) The premise of "summarize" is column and row *reduction*. Since we're calculating `max(Score)`, you need to do something similar to the other columns that you how to retain.  For instance, if grabbing the first of each is sufficient, then try `summarise(Score=max(Score), across(-Score, ~ first(.)))`.